# Make - Parameter for not recompiling existing .o-Files?

Tags: makefile

Yes, that is the question, how can I prevent make, or better the compiler, from recompiling already existing libraries (.o-Files)?

I call the makefile simply via make [-parameters], and if possible, I don't like to rewrite the makefile itself (the reason is, I have to work with a lot of them)?

Edit: Whoops, sorry, yes, I meant the object-files.

The problem is, I got a directory with several hundred .mk-Files for several hundred sub-programs/libraries/whatever. I call the mk-files in a loop:

```
foreach i ('ls *.ml')
make CFLAGS='[some parameters]' -f $i -B
end
```

Now when I do it like this, everytime a makefile gets called, it recompiles not only the programs, but for each mk-file the needed libraries and objects, which slow down the whole process a lot. So I don't want it to recompile these.

These makefiles were not written by me, and I really don't want to edit several hundreds of them, so I'm asking whether there is a parameter especially prohibiting overwriting.

Comment: A properly written makefile will only recompile the files if they need to be recompiled (their sources are newer than the object file). You almost certainly *want* make to do that. Is the problem that make is *always* rebuilding the object files? Because that likely means your makefiles are broken.

Comment: Or are you trying to say that you don't want `make` to rebuild `.o` files (which are called _object files_, by the way, not _libraries_) which alredy exist, EVEN IF the source files have been changed since the object files were last compiled?  That doesn't make sense, but it appears to be what you are asking, interpreted strictly.